# Adding multiple values into 1 user claim using JSON string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, permissions, claims-based-identity

I am using .net claims principal when i authenticate a user.  In our system a user has multiple permissions (can be up to 70).

Now instead of querying the database on each request a user makes i thought it would be good to store the permissions as a claim.  I tried to store each permission as a separate claim, but even getting to 10 permissions blows the size of the token up hugely.

So instead of adding 1 claim for 1 permission, i wondered if it would make a different if i added all permissions to 1 claim, and it does.  It keeps the size of the token small, yet i have the permissions i need.

Now to do this, i had to convert all my permissions from an array, into a JSON string and then save them as my claim.  To get the claim, i can then deserialize the string back into an array and i wont have to query the database at all.

Is this ok to do this, or is this very bad practice?  Am i making a ticking time bomb and it is going to blow up soon by doing this?

Example code here

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

// get user permissions
var permissions = await _permissionService.GetAllAsync(user);

// create list of all permissions
List<object> claimPermissions = new List<object>();

foreach (var item in permissions)
{
    claimPermissions.Add(new
    {
        Action = item.Action,
        Type = item.Type
    });
}

// convert list to json
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claimPermissions);

// add claim
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Permissions", json));
```

Comment: Does anyone have any opinions on this?

Comment: I would like someone to answer the question.  Forget about the Permissions part and just take it as 70+ items.  Would this be bad Practice?

Answer (score -2):

There is a standard list of most of the commonly used ClaimTypes in the class
System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes andI suggest you add those as separate claims. After that all the remaining claims can be added as just UserData. I am not sure why your app has up to 70 permissions? When you are designing your infrastructure it is wise to use the best practices, which is to use role based authorization. I t makes things easier. And remember these are tried and tested methods. The Windows Azure  Active Directory has the same design, and yet it can handle any authentication and authorization scenario.

If you need more information on how you can use Json Web Tokens to implement such an authentication mechanism, see my article on the subject on [here](http://stewartmbofana.co.za/blog/simple-authentication-using-json-web-tokens-in-asp-net-web-api-2-2/).

Given a Jwt, here is how you would check whether a user has permissions.

```
 private static ClaimsPrincipal ValidateToken(string token, string secret, bool checkExpiration)
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var payloadJson = JsonWebToken.Decode(token, secret);
        var payloadData = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(payloadJson);


        object exp;
        if (payloadData != null && (checkExpiration && payloadData.TryGetValue("exp", out exp)))
        {
            var validTo = FromUnixTime(long.Parse(exp.ToString()));
            if (DateTime.Compare(validTo, DateTime.UtcNow) <= 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    string.Format("Token is expired. Expiration: '{0}'. Current: '{1}'", validTo, DateTime.UtcNow));
            }
        }

        var subject = new ClaimsIdentity("Federation", ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);

        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        if (payloadData != null)
            foreach (var pair in payloadData)
            {
                var claimType = pair.Key;

                var source = pair.Value as ArrayList;

                if (source != null)
                {
                    claims.AddRange(from object item in source
                        select new Claim(claimType, item.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));

                    continue;
                }

                switch (pair.Key)
                {
                    case "name":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
                        break;
                    case "surname":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
                        break;
                    case "email":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Email));
                        break;
                    case "role":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
                        break;
                    case "userId":
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer));
                        break;
                    default:
                        claims.Add(new Claim(claimType, pair.Value.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String));
                        break;
                }
            }

        subject.AddClaims(claims);
        return new ClaimsPrincipal(subject);
    }
```

I hope this helps

Thanks

Stewart